# What's the point of having both action='store_true' and default=False in parser.add_argument?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have always read codes like this,

`parser.add_argument('--name', action='store_true', default=False, help='XXX')`

For example, this code [man-sf-emnlp/train.py - midas-research](https://github.com/midas-research/man-sf-emnlp/blob/393fcd91b8aeeb7e806e752dc771c27946bb16e0/train.py#L26)

But what is the point of setting `default=False` when you already set `action='store_true'`?

Comment: It's a stylistic choice to be explicit rather than implicit. That's generally in line with the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow questions should be about _a specific problem you actually face_. Do you have any problem this causes?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this is a specific question - and it doesn't have to be a question you actually face, it is perfectly fine to ask about things you don't grok, the question just have to be answerable.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Sorry I don't have big problems now, just having some difficulties in understanding these deep learning codes as a beginner.

Comment: @thebjorn, as for the "problem that you actually face" criteria, it's present in the Help Center, right next to the "practical" and "answerable" criteria; in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, see the first sentence of the second line: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*

Comment: I've answered a lot of SO about `argparse`, and don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: A default that might be useful is `default=argparse.SUPPRESS`.  'name' won't even appear in `args` if `--name` isn't used.

Answer (score 7):

There's no point. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action):

> `'store_true'` and `'store_false'` - These are special cases of `'store_const'` used for storing the values `True` and `False` respectively. In addition, **they create default values of `False` and `True` respectively.**

(added bold)

---

In the comments, [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) said, "It's a stylistic choice to be explicit rather than implicit", which is a fair point, but it also means that if you're editing the code and accidentally mismatch the `action` and `default`, it'll break:

```
>>> parser.add_argument('--name', action='store_true', default=True)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--name'])  # Good
Namespace(name=True)
>>> parser.parse_args([])  # Bad
Namespace(name=True)
```

And I think the implicit default is obvious anyway.

Comment: Not just obvious, but the only sensible default. Why use `--name` if it doesn't do anything different from *not* using `--name`?

Comment: @chepner Someone who's not familiar with argparse might assume that the default is to have it undefined, but I think that's unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The `__init__` for the `store_true` subclass is:

```
class _StoreTrueAction(_StoreConstAction):

    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 default=False,
                 required=False,
                 help=None):
        super(_StoreTrueAction, self).__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest,
            const=True,
            default=default,
            required=required,
            help=help)
```

Notice that it sets `default=False`.  The user code can override that, but what's the point?  This subclass is just a `store_const` where the `default` is `False` and the `const` is `True`.

`add_argument` takes a number of keyword parameters and creates an `Action` subclass object.  Different `actions` make use of different combinations of parameters.  `add_argument` takes a casual approach to required or superfluous parameters.  That is, there isn't a lot of code that checks that just the right parameters have been defined.

I'd leave it off since the default is the correct one.